# How to get Specific Data from JSON Response using PHP

Tags: php, json

In one of my applications I get a JSON format response data from a REST API. Which is as similar as the following:

```
{
   "Response": {
       "user_id": "12003",
       "username": "Shimul",
       "status": "active"
   },
   "ErrorMessage": "",
   "Status": 0
}
```

From this response, I just need to fetch `user_id` to process further operations in my application. But I can't identify how to decode this using PHP `json_decode()`

Can anyone tell me how can I decode this using `PHP` and fetch only `user_id` from this response?

Thanks

Comment: Please, provide the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json_decode take 2 parameters.

1. (string) json
2. (bool) assoc. If TRUE, the function will return array else object.

so you just need to do is:

```
<?php
$json = '{
      "Response": {
      "user_id": "12003",
      "username": "Shimul",
      "status": "active"
    },
  "ErrorMessage": "",
  "Status": 0
  }';

// By converting into array..

$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
$user_id = $array['Response']['user_id'];

//---------OR---------
// Using Object

$obj = json_decode($json);
$user_id = $obj->Response->user_id; 
?>
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show us what you tried so far and why it failed, but it's as simple as that:

```
<?php
$json = '{
   "Response": {
       "user_id": "12003",
       "username": "Shimul",
       "status": "active"
   },
   "ErrorMessage": "",
   "Status": 0
}';

var_dump(json_decode($json)->Response->user_id);
```